# WiFi AP overlapping

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

I would like to install 2 additional accesspoint to my existing network(1 modem with wifi) with the same SSID.

I read that overlapping is not a good thing in this situation.
What shall i do to make a stable wifi network?

Because i would like to access to wifi from everywhere in the house, so some kind of overlap is required.
In our neighborhood there are several wifinetworks so there is no channel which is empty.

Shall i separate them to 1,6,11 chanel, or leave them to select it automatically? or i have to set lower the transmission power to minimalize the overlap?
Or what could be the best solution?

thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can choose (depending on your hardware) two different channels, one in the 20MHz range, the other in the 40MHz range, then you might want to give your two accesspoint a fixed central channel, so that wherever the users are in the house, they'll never see their connection drop completely. For example, you can set one on the even channels, and the other on odds channels. There's no real rule of thumb here. You hear everywhere how to avoid channel 6 because it's the most-often used, which is true, but the closer to the AP, the better the signal, congestion or not.

Comment: @Didier WiFi operates in the 2.4GHz and 5GHz ranges. the 20MHz and 40MHz are for broadcast TV.

Comment: Sorry, I mispoke myself... :-) I meant "20MHz-40MHz channel bandwidth in the 2.4GHz band", not 20MHz or 40MHz as bands themselves, you're right. See here (among many others) for more details: https://bluegadgettooth.com/channel-bandwidth-20-40-80/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the channels you mention, I'm assuming you are limited to the 2.4GHz band. This band is separated, generally, into 11 channels. Those channels are 20MHz wide... however, some devices will use a larger channel width of 40MHz or even 60MHz. An access point configured for a 60 MHz wide channel 1 will actually occupy channel 1, 2, *and* 3. And then there's usually some "bleed" beyond that into yet more channels. Something to keep in mind. If possible you should consider going with wifi equipment capable of operating in the 5ghz band which not only has many, many more available channels but also doesn't have to compete with other non-wifi devices. While you're at it, get APs that support "roaming" which means they forcefully disconnect clients whose signal gets too weak (which will cause it to reconnect to a different AP).

Generally, the first thing you want to do in a situation like this is to perform a site survey of the location where wifi will be used. See what channels are occupied in what parts of the building. Chances are you don't have those channels all to yourself. I use [WiFi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer) on my Android smartphone for this.

If you configure your access points to use 20MHz wide channels, you can stack them 3 channels a part without serious issue. More is better... but there might not be enough unoccupied space on the 2.4GHz band. Yes, definitely specify your channels manually. You do not want to rely on auto configuration in this situation. You can give all the APs the same SSID and the devices should be smart enough to identify which AP is closest and use that. Some will even know how to roam between them... switching to the strongest as you move around the building.